# proof of a set problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

So i have been reading How to prove it by daniel velleman and i have been trying to wrap my head around a specific proof for about 2 hours now. The problem goes like this:

Let U be any set.
 Prove that there is a unique A ∈ P (U) such that for every B ∈
 P (U), A ∪ B = B. (keep in mind that P(U) means the power set of U).

This particular problem has a solution in the appendix which is the following:

Let A = ∅∈ P (U). Then clearly for any B ∈ P (U), A ∪ B =
 ∅ ∪ B = B.
 To see that A is unique, suppose that A' ∈ P (U) and for all
 B ∈ P (U), A' ∪ B = B. Then in particular, taking B = ∅, we can
 conclude that A' ∪ ∅ = ∅. But clearly A' ∪ ∅ = A
 , so we have A' = ∅ = A.

I understand the first part, that is that there is at least one possibility ( the empty set ) where A ∪ B = B. However I cannot grasp why assigning a particular value to the ARBITARY set B and then proving rather trivially that A' = A makes A unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove uniqueness, the standard way is to assume that there are two objects $A'$ and $A$ that satisfy the conditions and prove that they are actually equal.

So, the proof assumes that $\emptyset$ (this is $A$) and $A'$ both satisfy the given equality.  In other words, for ALL $B\in\mathcal{P}(U)$, $\emptyset\cup B=B$ and $A'\cup B=B$.

Now, the author does something sneaky.  Since you're allowed to choose any $B$, the author chooses $B=\emptyset$ (the empty set is an element of $\mathcal{P}(U)$, so it's a valid choice for $B$).

Now, $A'\cup B=B$ is supposed to be true, but then $A'\cup\emptyset=\emptyset$ is true.  Since $A'\cup\emptyset=A'$, you have $A'=\emptyset$

Comment: Okay, so you assume there are two objects, ∅ and A' that satisfy the conditions. However we do not yet know what A' is, how can we be sure that A′∪B=B is true for all sets in P(U) after only checking that one case holds (namely that B = ∅). What about the other sets in P(U) other than the empty set ?

Comment: @Alexander Because you assumed that $A'$ satisfies the conditions and the conditions are that $A'\cup B=B$ for all $B$.  When you assume the conditions, you're assuming that property.  Think of it like saying "if there were another $A'$ that satisfied the property for all $B$, then it would look like ..."

Comment: By the way i presume what you are reffering to is the following equivalence right?:
 ∃!x P(x) = ∃x P(x) ∧ ∀y∀z((P(y) ∧ P(z)) → y = z).

Comment: @АлександърГьорев Yes, that's the equivalence that I'm (essentially) using.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption is that $A' \cup B = B$ holds for any $B \in P(U)$. This means that you can always choose any desired element in $P(U)$ and you would still have the aforementioned equality. So, as the empty set is an element of $P(U)$, we are free to choose it and replace it in that equation.